# R New dataframe with binary columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a new dataframe, that shows if a promo code is being used on a specific date(binary not the actual sum\count) but also sums the amount of sales that code produced.

```
DATA:
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| Order Date    | Promo Code | Sales Amount | 
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   today20  |   50         |  
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   vip20    |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   today20  |   50         |  
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   vip20    |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   vip20    |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-27-20      |   pc20     |   25         |
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |            |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   vip20    |   50         |   
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| 10-27-20      |            |   25         |
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| ....          |      ....  |   ....       |
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| ....          |      ....  |   ....       |
+---------------+------------+--------------+


NEW DATAFRAME
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|Order Date     | today20    | vip20        |  pc20        | Sales Total  |
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 10-29-20      |   1        |   1          |    0         |  150.00      |
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 10-28-20      |   0        |   1          |    0         |  100.00      |
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 10-27-20      |   0        |   0          |    1         |   25.00      |
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| ....          |      ....  |   ....       | ....         |   ....       |
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| ....          |      ....  |   ....       | ....         |   ....       |
+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dcast

I prefer to use data.table, so

```
library(data.table)

dt=setDT(yourdf)

#This will give you the column names but with the sum in each column.
dt.wide=dcast(data=dt, formula = Order_date ~ Promo_code, fun.aggregate='sum', value.var='Sales_amount')

#Adds sales_total column
dt$Sales_total = apply(dt[,-c('Order_date'),with=F],1,sum)

#Converts promo_code columns to binary 
dt[,lapply(.SD,function(x) x[x>0]=1),.SDcols=unique(yourdf$Promo_code)]
```

Comment: It throws this error: Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) :

  attempt to apply non-function